# Replicating Map behaviour in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to replicate the Map class in TypeScript, not something serious. It's just a part of learning this language. So here's what I already have in place.

```js
import { IHashMap, KeyType, ValueType } from "./map";
import { hashFunction } from "./hashFunction";

class HashMap<T extends KeyType, U extends ValueType> implements IHashMap<T, U> {
  private ARRAY: U[];
  constructor() {
    this.ARRAY = new Array<U>(100);
  }
  public set<T extends KeyType, U extends ValueType>(key: T, value: U): void {
    const index = hashFunction(key);
    this.ARRAY[index] = value;
  }

  public get <T extends KeyType> (key: T): U {
      const index = hash(key);
      return this.ARRAY[index];
  }
}

// What I wanna achieve...
const map = new HashMap();
map["key1"] = "value1";
map["key2"] = "value2";

// Just like a regular Map() would do.
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this, a way to access the names of the properties in the class and do something with it. Something similar to what we could do in Python using `__setter__`.

Comment: Why don't you just use the [inbuilt one?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Liam I think the OP is talking about an object-like abstraction on top of `Map`, not the array map function, which doesn't appear to be related at all.

Comment: If it is just about index access - it could be allowed using Proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is *not* what a "regular `Map`" would do—array notation is for *object* properties, *not* `Map` entries. See the [Setting object properties section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#setting_object_properties) in the `Map` docs for details, but it boils down to:

> `let wrongMap = new Map()`
> `wrongMap['bla'] = 'blaa'`
> `wrongMap['bla2'] = 'blaaa2'`
> `console.log(wrongMap) // Map { bla: 'blaa', bla2: 'blaaa2' }`
>
> But that way of setting a property does not interact with
> the `Map` data structure. It uses the feature of the generic object. The
> value of `'bla'` is not stored in the `Map` for queries.

JS/TS don't allow operator overloading, which is what this would require, even if `[]` was an operator. So in the end, without some form of pre-processing, no.